# How does this function translate into a sum？

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I really don't understand how $f(x)=\arctan2x  $ and $f'(x)$$ $ translates into $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n2^{2n+1}x^{2n}$.
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2}{1+(2x)^2}=\frac{2}{1+4x^2}= 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-4x^2)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n2^{2n+1}x^{2n}
$$

Thanks

Comment: The given sum is wrong. Integrate $f'(x)$ from $0$ to $t$. You will get a series with only odd powers of $t$. Since the function is an odd function you cannot get a series with only even  powers of $x$.

Comment: thx...It was my fault, I will correct the problem, the really I  want to say is: $f(x)=arctan2x $ and $f'(x) $ can translate into $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n2^{2n+1}x^{2n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just work with $\text{arctan}(x)$ for now, as it makes formulas easier.

As you have noted, its derivative is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. We can now use a little trick, namely the formula for a geometric series:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x^2)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nx^{2n}$$
This works as long as $|-x^2| < 1$, i.e. $x\in (-1, 1)$.

For your case, the calculation is similar, with just a few multiplicative factors more.
Integrating this should then give you the function you are searching for; you seem to have a typo, but at the end of the day you should get
$$f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{2^{2n+1}}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$$